# google api key gets 401

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to call some endpoints on google cloud build but I just get 401 and I am wondering how to fix this?  In the end, I want to curl but if the website is not working, there is truly something wrong!  Here is the picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a group of API services/products on Google Cloud Platform support API keys without more authentication methods (OAuth). You can find these specific services [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys). In the same page that you posted, if you go down on the documentation there should be a "Authorization Scopes" section listing the required OAuth scopes that the API requires, if so, it means OAuth is needed in order to use the service.

I look at the [Cloud Build Rest Api Doc](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds/list) and indeed I can see OAuth is required, in addition to not being listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys). You need to implement OAuth for this specific Service (Cloud Build API).

Comment: thanks @JC98.  I was hoping to avoid OAuth as everyone I hear from says it takes soooo much work to get it working.  I have a new SO post now as I also can't get it working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450572/how-to-google-oauth-to-an-api-my-example-is-not-working