# How to google oauth to an api? My example is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to do this article for google cloud build

```
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication
```

I am guessing to use the service account email I generated the key from in that example AND for Audient, I put "" (which is probably the reason it's not working?).  I have no idea and can't find what in the world to put for audience.

**In addition to code below, I tried setting audience to 'https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com' which also did not work**

My code is the following...

```
public class GenToken {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Duration d = Duration.ofDays(365);
        String tok = generateJwt("/Users/dean/workspace/order/java/googleBuild/orderly-gcp-key.json",
                "mycloudbuilder@order-gcp.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "", d.toSeconds());

        System.out.println("tok="+tok);

        URL url = new URL("https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/order-gcp/builds");
        makeJwtRequest(tok, "GET", url);

    }

    public static String generateJwt(final String saKeyfile, final String saEmail,
                                     final String audience, final long expiryLength)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Date now = new Date();
        Date expTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(expiryLength));

        // Build the JWT payload
        JWTCreator.Builder token = JWT.create()
                .withIssuedAt(now)
                // Expires after 'expiraryLength' seconds
                .withExpiresAt(expTime)
                // Must match 'issuer' in the security configuration in your
                // swagger spec (e.g. service account email)
                .withIssuer(saEmail)
                // Must be either your Endpoints service name, or match the value
                // specified as the 'x-google-audience' in the OpenAPI document
                .withAudience(audience)
                // Subject and email should match the service account's email
                .withSubject(saEmail)
                .withClaim("email", saEmail);

        // Sign the JWT with a service account
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(saKeyfile);
        ServiceAccountCredentials cred = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(stream);
        RSAPrivateKey key = (RSAPrivateKey) cred.getPrivateKey();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, key);
        return token.sign(algorithm);
    }

    /**
     * Makes an authorized request to the endpoint.
     */
    public static String makeJwtRequest(final String signedJwt, String method, final URL url)
            throws IOException, ProtocolException {

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod(method);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + signedJwt);

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        buffReader.close();
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

The orderly-gcp-key.json has these attributes in it

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "myproj",
    "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nasdfsd\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "build-ci-mine@myproj.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "1167333552",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/build-ci-mine%40myproj.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

oops, my edit didn't get posted :(.  Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/orderly-gcp/builds
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1919)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.orderlyhealth.auth.websecure.GenToken.makeJwtRequest(GenToken.java:71)
at com.orderlyhealth.auth.websecure.GenToken.main(GenToken.java:26)
```

Comment: Hello according to the documentation you provided, the variable that you are not including in the parameters is the audience. The audience of a token is the intended recipient of the token, therefore, seems it is a  necessary parameter for the method to work.

Try again and let us know the result.

Comment: @HarifVelarde I have NO idea what that is but ran across a doc in google docs saying it's the host with http or something so I added "'https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com' as audience but that was a no-go.

Comment: What does your open api file look like?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am guessing that open api is the *.json file?  IF so I added that but if not, I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: Could be useful if you share with us the complete error trace

Comment: @HarifVelarde omg, I can't believe I missed that.  I thought I put that in there.  I added the 401 error I got.

Comment: it's too bad we can't do copy/paste curl requests for google like  many apis have.  Another option I am being asked is perhaps we don't use google at this point for this task.

Comment: 401 errors are typically related to the unauthorized access attempts, if you need to provide more details in order to solve this scenario maybe you could try to contact with google cloud support. https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: Also you can share with use the complete error trace, just remember delete sensitive information

Comment: @DeanHiller, you are calling a Cloud Endpoint service. For deploying this service, you use the `gcloud endpoints service deploy openapi.yaml`. What's the content of this yaml file? the security configuration is defined in it.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have no idea what that is.  I am trying to call a cloudbuild api https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/run and there is nothing about how to do oauth in those docs and I found this doc on oauth in google.  Am I not using the right document?  I thought all google services used oauth and there was no openapi.yaml and setup and I   can use glcoud command line to execute my trigger.

Comment: @HarifVelarde rough day yesterday.  I wrote the stack and never pushed post as I guess I got distracted.  I added it but there's not much value in it as it's just 401 and that's it :( but regardless, I figured I mine as well post it.

Comment: yup @guillaumeblaquiere, you got it!!!!  no worries.  totally understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that I better understood!!

When you try to reach a Google API, you have to use an access token. I have 2 code snippets for you.

Use Google Http client

```
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
        HttpRequestFactory factory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory(new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials));
        HttpRequest request = factory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb/builds"));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
        System.out.println(CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getContent(), Charsets.UTF_8)));
```

Use pure java connection

```
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb/builds").openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + credentials.refreshAccessToken().getTokenValue());

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        buffReader.close();
        System.out.println(result.toString());
```

You can rely on the platform environment. In local, perform a `gcloud auth application-default login` to set your credential as default default credential. On GCP, the component identity (the default service account or the service account that you define when you create the component), is used thanks to the method `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();`

Your dependency management need this (here in maven)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: A question that came up is we thought a token was generated PER 'audience' or url we want to talk to on google.  Your example though seems to generate a single JWT token for all endpoints?

Comment: You need audience for identity token. In this case it's access token and you can limit the range of the token by restricting it to scopes.